# Get accurate location in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, gps, cllocationmanager

I set the location accuracy with this setting:

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
```

And I get the location with this:

```
if let location = locations.first {
....
}
```

But it updates location several times and many of them are not accurate. For example when I find the location, it's about 100 meter away from the device location.

How do I get an accurate location?

I know that the first few locations are not accurate until the device gets a fix on the location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423836-desiredaccuracy):

> The receiver does its best to achieve the requested accuracy; however,
>   the actual accuracy is not guaranteed.

Because of this, you can't guarantee how close the detected locations are, but there are a couple of other things that you could try:

1. Use [`kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/kcllocationaccuracybestfornavigation). This should get you a more accurate reading, but with the cost of more battery usage.
2. Filter the locations, though I don't know if this is even possible, because the only data you have is what was received from the location manager that you are using.

Answer (score 3):

From experience over the years with core location. It takes sometime for the GPS chip to "Warm up" and sometimes reports several locations before getting a lock on. You will experience this more indoors rather than with clear view of the sky. Buildings with metal roofs also effect the accuracy. You can however ignore gps updates if they are in/out of a certain threshold using distanceFilter property (Specified in meters) [distanceFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423500-distancefilter) and setting desired accuracy using this property also [horizontalAccuracy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423599-horizontalaccuracy).

Comment: Thanks. How can I wait until the device gets a fix on location and then get it? Can I get the accuracy of location in percentage?

Comment: Unfortunately the accuracy isn't guaranteed and up to a 100 meters is known to be considered "fairly accurate" also it depends on the device you are using as they've gotten much better over the years. Have you tried to run your app outside to see if the lock on improves?

Answer (score 2):

You can check accuracy for every update you get, and filter locations until they get to reliable accuracy:

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print(manager.location!.horizontalAccuracy)

    if locations.last!.horizontalAccuracy <= manager.desiredAccuracy{
        print(manager.location)         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the horizontalAccuracy property of the location (CLLocation). This is measured in meters. You can use this property to disregard location readings which are not accurate enough.